# How do you call functions using function pointers in Lua with SWIG binding?

Tags: c, lua, swig

I have C code which looks something like the following:

```
typedef int (*SIMPLEFUNC)(int);

SIMPLEFUNC foo = NULL;

void setup_foo(void) {
    foo = ...;
}
```

I wrap this with SWIG with a bare-bones .i file, then can use it in Lua. I am able to call `setup_foo()` from Lua. I can see the variable `foo`. But I am unable to call `foo` as a function from Lua. It appears as userdata.

```
local mylib = require('mylib')
mylib.setup_foo()
print(mylib.foo)
print(mylib.foo(3))
```

I get output like this:

```
setup_foo() has been called
userdata: 0x1b441c8
PANIC: [string "bootstrap0"]:86: attempt to call a userdata value (field 'foo')
stack traceback:
    [string "bootstrap0"]:86: in main chunk
```

**Question**

Is there a way to call function pointers such as `foo` from my Lua code when using SWIG?

Is there some SWIG configuration that might help?

If not, what is the best way to modify my C code to make it work?

**Edit**

At a higher level, I solved this problem by switching to Selene instead of SWIG. Selene allows rebinding functions in the Lua state at runtime easily.
https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is to simply expose a function that calls that function pointer:

```
SIMPLEFUNC foo = NULL;

int call_foo(int i) {return foo(i);}
```

This would of course be in your `.i` file. You don't want to expose it to C directly; it's just a helper function for Lua's sake.

There may be a more direct way of handling this from SWIG. Maybe some typemap construct or somesuch. But this is the simplest way. Besides, it's not like SWIG would allow you to shove a Lua function into that function pointer.